# Cordova plugin network crash if no wifi connection

Tags: cordova

I have this simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
        }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i launch the app in a genymotion device, if the wifi connection is on, all work fine; but if i set off the wifi connection the appa crash....
What is bad? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the plugin and reinstalling it from the repository:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.network-information

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
```